# Inline translate Chrome Bug?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, localisation, chrome-browser

Maybe it's just me, but in Chrome browser inline translate does not work. The red boxes are shown and if I hover the mouse the book icon appears but if I click it nothing happens. I had the same problem on different servers.

Other browser like Firefox and IE are fine.

Is there a bugfix for this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'doesn't work'? It does not appear, it does not save, do you get js errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the inline translation feature is broken in Google Chrome.  Back when the inline translation feature was originally developed, Magento made use of a non-standard `translate` attribute in DOM elements to flag translatable text.

Since then, Google Chrome has a feature where a default `translate` property is added to every DOM node available in javascript (over simplification).

This, in turn, interfers with Magento's PrototypeJS xpath code used to implement the translation feature.  Specifically, this

```
if (!$(target).match('*[translate]')) {
    target = target.up('*[translate]');
}
```

I solution I came up with [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113914/removing-chromes-translate-dom-property) was to add the following bit of javascript to every page when inline translations are active.

```
if(Object.__defineGetter__)
{
    var hasTranslateAttribute = function(){
        return $(this).hasAttribute("translate");
    };
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $$('*').each(function(theElement){
             theElement.__defineGetter__("translate", hasTranslateAttribute);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's still an issue.  But the line that's the problem is a couple down from that and I changed it like so:
//if (target && $(target).match('*[translate]')) {
if (target && $(target).readAttribute('translate')) {

Answer (score 5):

For Enterprise customers, there is a Magento core patch available (SUPEE-1373) which was tested by us and works.

It basically replaces all the `translate` properties by `data-translate` across the code.

Comment: Is it just me or has this "SUPEE-1373" patch just vanished of the internet? http://google.com/search?q="supee-1373"#q=%22supee-1373%22+-magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: @7ochem: The patch is only available via Magento Enterprise support. Unfortunately they did not fix it in CE 1.9 even the patch was available before the release of CE 1.9

Comment: I've gone though the whole file list in my EE technical resources, but I can't find it...

Comment: Just open a support request and ask for the patch.

Answer (score -1):

The solution provided by Alan Storm works. To make it work across the entire site, just add the snippet to /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate/Inline.php, right after

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new TranslateInline('translate-inline-trig', '<?php echo $ajaxUrl ?>', '<?php
    echo Mage::getDesign()->getArea() ?>');
```

That's line 278 in 1.7.

Comment: Really? Core change? At the very least, suggest that user use Magento's rewrites. There are other ways to effect this change without a rewrite.

Comment: I added it into the javascript file of my template.